# PHP CSV export not working after 10000 Records

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export, export-to-csv

PHP export csv not working when user have more than 10000 rows.it takes so much time for export csv and after some times CSV dies.

i have also set `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` and set_time_limit.

I want to export more than 10000 records, into csv.

My code is given below:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Content-disposition: xls" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = Mycsv.csv");
header("Content-type: application/x-download");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));
echo $out;
exit;
```

Comment: Where do You get `$out`?

Comment: i have fetch data from database and store in $out varible through loop.

Comment: Then maybe You are using too much memory. Turn on the error reporting to see - `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: You should not put such large data in $out variable. Instead start printing the rows as you loop through them. This way, the browser immediately shows a File Save dialog and a progress bar with no clear indication of when the file download will complete. But hey, some visual feedback is better than no visual feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the **Content-Length** strlen($out) doesn't match the downloaded file size due to the encoding of some special characters.

Try to comment the line `header("Content-Length: " . strlen($out));` to see if it works or not.